# Instantiate a List of Parent class with Subclass

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class ParentCollection
{
   public List<ParentObject> MyList { get; set; }

   public ParentCollection(){}
}
```

`ParentObject` has a subclass that inherits from it, `ChildObject`. `ParentCollection` also has the following subclass:

```
public class ChildCollection : ParentCollection
{
   public ChildCollection() : base()
   {
      this.MyList = new List<ChildObject>();
   }

   private void Filter()
   {
      this.MyList = this.Objects.Where(p => p.Age > 18).ToList();
   }
}
```

The line `this.MyList = new List<ChildObject>();` is throwing a `Cannot implicitly convert type error`. The `Filter()` method is also throwing a type error.

My understanding is that the List of parent objects should allow for instantiation using the child object, since that object inherits from the parent.

Comment: Make `ParentCollection` public

Comment: You should read about [covariance and contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is although `ChildObject` can be a child of `ParentObject`, `List<ChildObject>` is not a child of `List<ParentObject>`. `List<ChildObject>` is a object of type `List` and so is the `List<ParentObject>`

You can change your `ParentCollection` like this to achieve what you want.

```
abstract class ParentCollection
{
    public IEnumerable<ParentObject> MyList { get; set; }

    public ParentCollection() { }
}
```

You might also want to look into [Covarience and Contravarience.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

Comment: I did not give code for ParentObject and ChildObject. ChildObject is a child of ParentObject.

Comment: That does not mean List<ChildObject> is child of List<ParentObject>

Comment: So is there a way to achieve the type of inheritance that I am after?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that allowing write access to a list of a derived type through a base interface can let you add objects of the wrong type to the list.

However, if you only require enumerated read access to the list, you could do this:

```
public abstract class ParentCollection
{
    public IEnumerable<ParentObject> MyList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ParentCollection()
    {
    }
}
```